# session attribute transfer through jquery from servlet to HTML

Tags: jquery, jsp

I send some parameters through jQuery from a HTML form to a servlet for a MySQL interrogation, and that's OK. If **I want to intercept back a session attribute (not DOM one) through the jQuery, before going to the jsp**, it fails. Putting *this.responseText* **in jQuery/jScript** together with slice() it may work, but the text is obviously too large and silly to be processed so not able to promt & stop inside the initial HTML file.

*For the moment I got an workaround solution*: **set the attribute pAlert in the servlet** (having two different possible values – Selection OK/ Wrong Selection), capture it in the jsp file (inside a hidden element) and process by invoking an DOM element event, as see in the code below, with a promt, if wrong selection. However, it should be a simpler solution, with the promt triggered from jQuery inside initial HTML, but not from jsp file. The problem looks to be an old one, but I found not yet an answer. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. I made it so detailed because the question may look old. Thank you in advance!

**jQuery code**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#refreshButton')
        .click(function () {
            var value1 = document.getElementById("idsectiune").value;
            var value2 = document.formular.CuAl.value;
            var value3 = document.getElementById("idizol").value;
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "Sp";
            type = "text";
            var params = "var1=" + value1 + "&var2=" + value2 + "&var3=" + value3;
            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (http.readyState === 4 && http.status === 200) {
                    window.location = "index.jsp";
                } else {
                    var v3 = "${sessionScope.promt}";
                    alert(v3);
                }
            };
            http.send(params);
        });
});
```

**Servlet code** to set back the attribute:

```
List<Cond> ls = null;    
ls = DBAccess.getQuery(strQuery, strWhereQry);    
int i = 0;    
String promt;    
if (ls.get(0).getId() != 0) {    
    int ix = 1;    
    ..........    
    promt = "Good selection!";    
    session.setAttribute("pAlert", "0");    
    } else {
            promt = "Wrong selection!";
            session.setAttribute("pAlert", "1");
        }                 
    session.setAttribute("sp", ls);
    session.setAttribute("promt", promt);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```

jsp file

```
function alertare() {
    var v = document.getElementById("idpAlert").value;
    if (v === "1") {
        var rasp = confirm("You must go back: select again!");
        if (rasp)
            window.location = "index.html";
        else
            document.getElementById("idTest").value = "0";
    }
}
function tempAlert() {
    if (document.getElementById("idTest").value === "0") {
        document.getElementById("idTest").value = "1";
        setTimeout(alertare, 3000);
    }
}
<div onmouseover="tempAlert()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a kind of answer: it's not with session attribute, but with "response". The other important issue is the related servlet path not to reach the code of    "rd.forward(request, response);"

in the servler:

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");    
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");    
response.getWriter().write(promt);
```

in the HTML file changed the jQuery to this form:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#refreshButton').click(function () {    
        var value1 = document.formular.sect.value;    
        var value2 = document.formular.CuAl.value;    
        var value3 = document.formular.izol.value;    
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();    
        var url = "Sp";    
        type = "text";    
        $.ajax({    
            type: "POST",    
            url: url,    
            data: ({var1: value1, var2: value2, var3: value3}),    
            success: function (data) {    
                var v = data.charAt(1, 1);    
                if (v === "=") {    
                    alert(data);    
                } else    
                    window.location = "index.jsp";    
            }    
        });    
    });    
});
```

Comment: still to see how to get the response with the first above jquery form